# How to crop other layers to a selection from a different layer? Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections, crop

In photoshop, let's say I have 3 layers. Layer A and B have default background images. In layer C, I make the shape of something, let's say a car. I select the outline using the Quick Selection Tool. How do I crop Layers A and B to this selection, so that I can get the portion of those images to this selection?

Comment: What you want is not to crop, but to _mask_ the other layers. Or _cut_ using the selection. There are several questions on the site where you can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only crop images in Rectangular/Square Shape, no curved lines.
In your case after you made a selection of your car, click on Layer A or B while selection is active then `right click` inside selection and chose `select inverse` then press `backspace` or `delete`.
By doing that, you will have the background in the shape of the car. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Copy paste - Semi-Destructive

1. Select you shape (if you have a shape created on layer C simply hold "CTRL and click" on the layer's picture)
2. Select the layer you want to crop and press "CTRL and J". This will create a new layer with what you had in your selection.
3. "CTRL and click" on this new layer's picture to select it, then go to "Image>Crop"

Result:

This will crop the image of one layer to the smallest rectangle and make anything outside the selection and alpha channel (transparent)

[image: Method 1 Result]

Method 2: Masks - Non-Destructive

1. Select you shape (if you have a shape created on layer C simply hold "CTRL and click" on the layer's picture)
2. In the layers panel create a new group (the little folder icon) then click "add layer mask" (the little rectangle with a hole in it icon to the right of fx)
3. Move layers A and B into this new group

Result:

This will mask your layers A and B to the selection. Show or hide layers to see the one you want, or if you want a different selection for each layer you can make masks on the layers themselves instead of using a group. The pros to using masks is that the original image stays the same. You can even drag it around without having to fix the selection.

[image: Method 1 Result]

Hope this helps!